In KML, I use Region and maxLodPixels to limit zoom levels. If I import this into PostGIS, how would I store that data?
I import geometry from KML files into a postGIS database, using geodjango.
For the sake of simplicity say there's a single folder with some features, and a region definition which looks like this:
    <Region>
      <LatLonAltBox>
        <north>38.75</north>
        <south>38.625</south>
        <east>-122.375</east>
        <west>-122.5</west>
      </LatLonAltBox>
      <Lod>
        <minLodPixels>450</minLodPixels>
        <maxLodPixels>-1</maxLodPixels>
      </Lod>
    </Region>

but the bottom line is that each feature ends up in the following model in geodjango:

class Feature(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    geom = models.GeometryField(null=True, blank=True)
    folder = models.ForeignKey(Folder, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="features")
    # and a ton of other stuff irrelevant to this question

I feel like what I should be doing is converting the Region definition in the KML into a max_zoom and min_zoom each ranging between 0 and 22, attached either directly to the feature or to the folder, then when serving vector tiles for location x,y,z use the z value to filter out features in this range.
This might look something like:

class Feature(models.Model):
    # ...
    min_zoom = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    max_zoom = models.IntegerField(default=22)

Am I on the right track, or is there something more deeply embedded into postgis that allows me to do this at database level within the geometry definitions themselves?
